# Can't compile Python codes via CMD

Tags: python-2.7, command-prompt

I can't get my system to compile python codes in command prompt. I've set my path variables and all. Python is still reported as an unrecognized command.

[image: Path variable settings]
[image: path variable setting2]

Comment: What is the error you receive? And what command are you running? Also Neither of those two screenshots shows that `python` is actually in your `PATH`

Comment: I have been able to resolve the issue.  I  used windows powershell. My new trouble is that I cannot install pip and consequently, twilio. I'm taking the "programming foundations with python" on Udacity. I'm using python 2. ANy help offered will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `;C:\Python27` at the end of the variable name `PATH` instead of `PY_PATH`.

Then open a new CMD window and type:

```
echo %path%
```

Comment: Blowing away the existing `PATH` seems like a terrible idea. *Adding* it to `PATH` might be useful.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are absolutely right!  I have updated my answer.